# How do I programmatically access an iPhone's noise cancelling function?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am attempting to create a noise cancellation app and was wondering if I could go about doing this by using the same noise cancellation function that the iPhone uses when it is in a phone call. Thank you for any assistance in helping me do this!

Answer (score -2):

The noise cancellation in iPhone uses multiple streams from several microphones. I guess you will not have this data in your application. Why not take a look at more simpler implementation of noise cancellation ? For example, take a look at Audacity.